# NotFoundError: Node was not found on removeChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm

I am trying to update the state whenever the `track` event is kicked off (tracking.js). After I grab all the moved objects and try to re-add them to the state I get a `NotFoundError: Node was not found`. I think it might be because I'm referencing the wrong `this` but earlier in the event I reference `this.state.hotspots` without an issue

```
componentDidMount () {
    tracking.ColorTracker.registerColor('red', function(r, g, b) {
        if (r > 175 && g < 90 && b < 90) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    this.tracker = new window.tracking.ColorTracker("red")

    $('#img').reel({
        frames: "360",
        images: "src/components/cascadion/pics/cascadion/Cascadio2017 360 turn 06__####.png",
    })

    this.tracker.on('track', event => {

        let hotspots = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.hotspots))

        this.state.hotspots.map(function(hotspot){
            var cords = event.data.reduce((acc, point) => {
                if (point.x == hotspot.x && point.y == hotspot.y){
                    return point
                } else {
                    return (
                        Math.abs(acc.x - hotspot.x) > Math.abs(point.x - hotspot.x) && Math.abs(acc.y - hotspot.y) > Math.abs(point.y - hotspot.y)
                    ) ? point : acc;
                }
            }, hotspot);

            var h = hotspots.find(function(element) {
              return element.hotspot_id == hotspot.hotspot_id;
            });

            h.x = cords.x
            h.y = cords.y

            hotspots[h.id] = h

        })

        this.setState({
            hotspots: hotspots,
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Because the closure is different so you're getting the tracker as `this` instead?

Comment: its gotta be something like that. But I can get the state here: `let hotspots = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.hotspots))` so why cant I `setState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in when the component tried to render. I needed to wrap the `<img/>` element in its own div:

### This doesnt work:

```
var CascadionImg = ({click}) => (
        <img 
            id="img"
            width="850"
            height="600"
            ref={img => this.img = img}
            src={pic}
            onClick={click}
        />

);
```

### This works:

```
var CascadionImg = ({click}) => (
    <div>
        <img 
            id="img"
            width="850"
            height="600"
            ref={img => this.img = img}
            src={pic}
            onClick={click}
        />
    </div>

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here inside on track event, in order to make your

```
this.setState({
        hotspots: hotspots,
    })
```

work you need to use it like this

```
        h.x = cords.x
        h.y = cords.y

        hotspots[h.id] = h

     this.setState({
        hotspots: hotspots,
    })
    })
})
```

but if you want to use in previous place you have to specify by using 'this.state.hotspots'